# Extract value from JMSByte message

Tags: arrays, regex, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Hi I have a consumer subscribe to a topic and receive the Byte Message.

The task i want to accomplish is to extract the value from below string i converted.

The code i used to convert Byte message is below:

```
if (message instanceof BytesMessage){
            BytesMessage byteMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
            byte[] byteData = null;
            try {
                byteData = new byte[(int) byteMessage.getBodyLength()];
                byteMessage.readBytes(byteData);
                byteMessage.reset();
            }catch (JMSException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String stringMessage =  new String(byteData);
            System.out.println(stringMessage);
        }
```

The stringMessage us show as below:

> 2179032   TradeId701118403 clearedTradeUsi
>   SW005285900447503296# clearedTradeUsiIssuer
>   1010051�zzz�cleared���i

i want to extract each value seperately like below. But right now i do not have any clue how to do that.. Could anyone help me with that?

TradeId: 70111840

clearedTradeUsi: SW005285900447503296

clearedTradeUsiIssuer: 1010051

Comment: Please show how you're *writing* the bytes to the BytesMessage when it's sent.

Comment: Hi Justin, i do not have code for sending message.. that is a vendor app, i just know this is a byte message i could get from ActiveMQ...

Comment: To properly deserialize a byte array you essentially need to perform the serialization process in reverse. String data can be serialized in many many different ways so without knowing what method/process was used it's going to be difficult to deserialize it with certainty. You're going to have to reverse engineer it and I'm not sure how much help you can get with this task. This basic problem is what all file formats, wire protocols, etc. solve. Is the vendor not willing or able to provide you with this information?

Comment: @JustinBertram you got the point. I think it is google proto buf

Comment: @JustinBertram By the way, do you know what is the proper way to convert a proto byte message to string?

Comment: If you want help converting a protobuf to a string I recommend that you clarify your question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged your question with regex, I'll provide some regex solutions to find the fields.

For the trade id

```
    TradeId\s?(\d+)
```

This will allow for a space to be added before the id like there is for some of the other values. The \s? matches none or one space.

For the clearedTradeUsi

```
clearedTradeUsi\s?(\w+)
```

For the clearedTradeUsiIssuer

```
clearedTradeUsiIssuer\s?(\d+)
```

Each of these regular expressions will match the respective id which will be put into group 1.

Comment: Hi, i tried you solution, but for some how it did not find the tradeId:

Comment: 2178564
 mxTradeId700825209��i

Comment: String stringMessage =  new String(byteData);
   String regexNB ="mxTradeId\\s?(\\d+)";
   Pattern murexNB = Pattern.compile(regexNB);
   Matcher nb = murexNB.matcher(stringMessage);
   if (nb.find()) {
    System.out.println(nb.group());
   }

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/104222   i use this link to test, and i think it worked for there is no chnaging line or space between name and value pair. do you know how to resolve the space and new line? Thanks

Comment: [https://regex101.com/r/fUzIzA/1] I don't know if the problem is with escaping?
`String stringMessage = new String(byteData); String regexNB ="mxTradeId\s?(\d+)"; Pattern murexNB = Pattern.compile(regexNB); Matcher nb = murexNB.matcher(stringMessage); if (nb.find()) { System.out.println(nb.group()); } `